# How to make the HR review their estimated range of salary?

Tags: interviewing, salary, applications

I was phoned by an HR manager for a position I applied 3 months ago.

Some day after the application, I applied for a similar position promoted by a recruiting company; but after a discussion, the recruiter and I we found out together the propoted position actually was the same position I had already applied for.
Even though having already applied by my own stopped the recruiting operator to issue my profile to the company, we had a conversation long enough to understand not only salary range for such position but also that my salary expectations based on experience, skills, position and prestige of the company were weighted very well.

Nevertheless, the HR of the company at the phone made a rough estimation based only on my graduations and years of service (I know because she was "thinking loud") without paying attention to the skills and experience for the role; at the end she estimated a range lower than what the recruiter told me and then also below my expectations.
From my side, due to the long time passed from the application and discussion with the recruiting company and without the job description with me, I totally forgot that I matched more than 90 % with that position (e.g. in terms of required skills and affinity with my current role) and then I did not (wrongly) debate the estimation the HR made.
However, at the further kind insisting request from the HR to share my salary expectations, I was determined to propose the salary expectation I discussed with the recruiter months ago. The HR took note without commenting. At my question about her pinion on that she said something like she will have to make new calculations before to express an opinion.
At the end, she proposed me an interview with the persons involved in such position (which was the original goal of the call).

Doubts: When and how may I make her look at my skills so that she can compare my skills and affinity with the required ones? Should I or it is better to wait for the interview and the steps after?

Answer (score 4):

You can't make them do anything. If they grant you and interview and offer you the job, you can accept the salary they offer you, negotiate a higher salary, or decline their offer.

Comment: Yes, but my salary expectation represent also a parameter in the selection, I think: if they find somebody else asking less, the could even cross me off from the list, couldn't they?

Comment: Not cross you off the list, but select the person asking for less if equally qualified.

Answer (score 2):

**You make an offer and they take it or leave it.**

In a lot of cases, there is very little flexibility on the salary range. I used to work for the government and those ranges were set in meetings with a bunch of people. I could never imagine them being re-done for a particular candidate if simply because it would take a long time to get those people together. While most private sector businesses are not that extreme, everything from pay equity lawsuit risk to union agreements to team budgets to head office approval can be involved in setting rates of pay.

It probably also is not worth it for you. If you are running into the top of the range now and need to bust through that to get your market rate of pay, imagine what it will be like when you want a raise...

Comment: Totally agree with the last point, but do not forget a detail I mentioned: she made the estimation in front of me simply by looking at my cv in that moment. Furthermore, when I asked how much is the budget for such position (before giving my expectation), she did not know or at least she told me so.